# What template is that

Tags: templates

I hope this kind of question is authorized. I am looking for the template of this document which is part of the book Handbook of Homotopy Theory, editied by Haynes Miller. The chapter in the snapshot is by Tyler Lawson. I hope it is some well known opensource template ! Note that of course I did spend time trying to find it, without success. [image]

Comment: Unfortunatly this is a TeX generated from the corresponding nLab page, not the tex of the book. Thank you though. <edit> the previous comment was deleted

Comment: yes sorry I had already deleted comment, as I said it was a quick search:-)

Comment: most of the chapters listed at https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Handbook+of+Homotopy+Theory are on arxiv where you can get the original author source, if that doesn't look like the printed book then most likely it is reset in a publisher style which will be private.

Comment: I hadn't realized that Overleaf proposes so many templates, and indeed I found the one I'm looking for among them ! It's called Krantz book template.
I had already checked all the arxiv versions, which are all formatted differently unfortunatly. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

The template is Krantz book template. Thanks D. Carlisle for helping me find it.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/199842)

Comment: Well, the answer is my own answer and I have to wait for two days before accepting it, I don't understand your comment.